# ggplot2 - x-axis ticks and labels not compatible with regression line (geom_smooth and geom_abline)

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, axis

I want to plot the relationship of `xval` and `yval` with a regression line and the x-axis labels from `xlab` of the following dataset:

```
# Reproduce data
df <- data.frame(xlab = c("C","W","I","Y","F","L","H","V","N","M","R","T","D","G","A","K","Q","S","E","P", "B", NA, "U","Z","X"),
                 xval = c(0.000, 0.004, 0.090, 0.113, 0.117, 0.195, 0.259, 0.263, 0.285, 0.291, 0.394, 0.401, 0.407, 0.437, 0.450, 0.588, 0.665, 0.713, 0.781, 1.000,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 yval = c(376744, 143848, 796132, 401820, 500313, 1373674,  383024,  981537,  831832,  295145,  910981, 1001490,  910590, 1999530, 1474808, 1001585,  860611, 1510439, 1225631, 1290983, 21, NA, 24, 48, 1034))
```

Details:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   25 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ xlab: Factor w/ 24 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 3 21 9 23 6 11 8 20 13 12 ...
 $ xval: num  0 0.004 0.09 0.113 0.117 0.195 0.259 0.263 0.285 0.291 ...
 $ yval: num  376744 143848 796132 401820 500313 ...
```

I first tried to use `geom_smooth()` in two different ways where once the labelling is satisfying but the regression line isn't and in the second approach it's just the opposite:

**1. Labelling good, `geom_smooth` bad**

```
p1 <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x = as.factor(xval), y = yval))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = as.character(df$xlab),
                   breaks = df$xval)+
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", 
              data = df, aes(x = xval, y = yval))+ 
  labs(x ="my x-axis title",
       y = "my y-axis title")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1.1))
p1
```

[image: p1]

**2. Labelling bad, `geom_smooth` good**

```
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = xval, y = yval))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = as.character(df$xlab),
                   breaks = df$xval)+
  stat_smooth(method = "lm")+ 
  labs(x ="my x-axis title",
       y = "my y-axis title")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1.1))
p2
```

[image]

I gave it a further attempt with `geom_abline` fitting my own model. However here are the spacings of the x-axis-ticks unequal.

**3. Labeling good, `geom_abline` good, x-axis spacing bad**

```
# other approach with abline
model.lm.tr <- lm(aa_freq_tr ~ disorderpropensity, data = df)
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = xval, y = yval))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(labels = as.character(df$xlab),
                     breaks = df$xval)+
  geom_abline(intercept = coefficients(model.lm.tr)[1], slope = coefficients(model.lm.tr)[2])+
  labs(x ="my x-axis title",
       y = "my y-axis title")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1.1, vjust = 0.5))
p3
```

[image]

Does anyone have suggestions on how I get a plot with the x-axis spacing and labeling of 1 together with a regression line of 2 (or 3 is also good enough)?

Answer (score 1):

The trick with using `stat_smooth()` and a discrete axis is to redefine the grouping for the stat layer. By default `ggplot2` is assuming that stats should be calculated within each discrete group (defined by the discrete axis). So to override that behavior you can set `aes(group = 1, ...)`, which is setting a dummy group that includes the entire data plotted.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(xval), y = yval))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = as.character(df$xlab),
                   breaks = df$xval)+
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = 1))
```

[image]

I dropped the `labs` and `theme` adjustments just to keep the example minimal and moved the major `aes()` definitions into the initial layer to minimize redundant type.

Disclaimer: Just because you can do this, doesn't mean it is the best way to visualize the patterns in your data. Consider carefully the conclusions you are making.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! However, it's not quite clear to me what  `aes(group = 1)` does. Could you explain that in more detail? Why does `group = 2` result in the same? And why does `group = df$xlab` let the regression line disappear?

Comment: `group = whatever` is setting a universal group. The value doesn't matter, as long as it is constant across all observations so they are treated as part of the same regression. `group = df$xlab` makes the regression line disappear because it is defining  ~20 discrete groups and since each group has only one value, no regression is computable.

Comment: I'm still wondering why the slope differs between your suggestion and No. 2 & 3 from the question...

Comment: It is because your requirements are incompatible: you cannot have force a regression line to have equal spacing. Either your data is continuous (like in your #2 and #3) or it is discrete (#1). In #1 and in this answer, you are showing C = 0, W = 1, I = 2, Y = 3,... and the regression line in #2 and #3 is spaced by the real data (C=0, W=0.004, I=0.090...).

Comment: I'm actually only interested in the order of appearance of the letters. The real values (C=0, W=0.004...) are just used for statistical purpose. Is there a way to overlay the regressionline (calculated beforehand with the continuous values) on the plot (i.e. #1) with discrete values?
Or in other words: Can I plot the discrete values (`xlab`) and tell `stat_smooth` (or any regression function) to use continuous values (`xval`) for its calculations?